# execute cmd commands as admin with java code

Tags: java, cmd, admin

I want to turn the firewall in Windows on and off from java code. To do this, I need to execute a cmd command with admin privileges.

I tried this, but it is not running as admin.

```java
public void execute_cmd2() {
       
            Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd");
            OutputStream outputStream = exec.getOutputStream();
            InputStream inputStream = exec.getInputStream();
            PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"utf-8"));
            printStream.println("netsh advfirewall set allprofile state off");
            //printStream.println("winget uninstall \"voidtools.Everything\"");
            printStream.flush();
```